# Flash: Dispatching/handling events

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, flexbuilder

I have Flash application (main_container.swf) that loads another swf file (page1.swf).

I want to dispatch an event when page1 has finished, to tell the main_container to close page1.

Is this how you dispatch an event from page1 to the main_container?

```
parent.dispatchEvent(new Event("pageFinish", true));
```

Then how do you catch the event from the main_container? I tried this but it didn't work.

```
loader.addEventListener("pageFinish", OnPage1Finish);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is just

```
// main, somewhere
loader.content.addEventListener("imDone", imDoneListener);

// page1 timeline/doc class
dispatchEvent(new Event("imDone"));
```

Of course, you have to wait until the loader has a .content for you to add
a listener to, you could either wait for a Event.INIT from loader.contentLoaderInfo
before adding your complete listener or dispatching on the loader:

```
// page1 again, parent.dispatchEvent() would also work
// if you don't reparent the content (which is a bad idea, it confuses Loader)
loaderInfo.loader.dispatchEvent(new Event("imDone"));
```